# How to spy chained functions?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, spy

I have a structure like the code below:

```
public class MyClass {
   private A myA;

   public callSomeMethod() {}
}

public class A {
   private B myB;
   // getter and setter
}

public class B {
  private BigDecimal C;
  // getter and setter
}
```

And in my tests I have something like that:

```
public class MyClassTest {

@InjectMocks
private MyClass underTest = new MyClass ();

@Spy
private A a;

@Test
public void shouldPass() {

X x = new X();
x.setSomething(10);

// given
stubData();
doReturn(x).when(a).getB().getC(); // <-- Here I got the error

// when
MyClass myc = underTest.callSomeMethod();

// then
assertEquals(myc.getC, 10);
}

}
```

How to use doReturn to "mock" the value when I a chained methods (in the example: getC) is called?

Comment: I already tried doReturn(x).when(agetB()).getC() without success.

Answer (score 1):

`a` may be a spy, but the result of its `getB()` method isn't. You'll need to set that up.

Something like this should work to get `getB()` to return a spy:

```
doAnswer(i -> spy(i.callRealMethod())).when(a).getB();
```

That returns a different spy each time `getB()` is called, so if that method always returns the same instance, you can cache it:

```
B b = spy(a.getB());
doReturn(b).when(a).getB();
```

You can put all of this in an `@BeforeEach` method so that you don't have to repeat this for every test.

Comment: In the first example, who is i ?

Comment: `doAnswer` takes an `Answer` (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html), which is a functional interface. It takes one argument, the `InvocationOnMock` (that's `i`), which can be used to get the actual arguments or, in this case, call the actual method. You can do anything you want, but you need to end with returning the method's return value (`null` for `void`). It's like `doReturn` but you can do simple or complex calculations, depending on your need.

Comment: I think that for my code to work, you need a cast, because `callRealMethod()` returns `Object`.